# The method (List<String>) in the type is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)

Tags: java, json

I am having a runtime error on setid method saying " The method ids(List) in the type dtoClass is not applicable for the arguments (boolean) ". below is the code. What error it could be

```
JSONArray jsonInnerArray = null;
jsonInnerArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("ids");
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();    
dtoClass.setid(ids.add(jsonInnerArray.get(i).toString()));
```

DTO Class

```
public class dtoClass{
private List<String> ids = null;

public List<String> getids() {
    return tracking_ids;
}
public void setids(List<String> ids) {
    this.ids = ids;
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `ids.add` returns a `boolean`. See javadoc for [`List.add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29)

To solve the issue change the code to:

```
JSONArray jsonInnerArray = null;
jsonInnerArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("ids");
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();    
ids.add(jsonInnerArray.get(i).toString())
dtoClass.setid(ids);
```